# CSS property to fill parent div with image, centered, and change size to fill parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, pug

I have the following website, where a parent div that scales dynamically with browser size contains a child div with an image. The desired effect is as follows: https://shibori-demo.squarespace.com/workshops-shibori/

My `pug` code is as follows:

```
article.eventlist-event.eventlist-event--upcoming.eventlist-event--hasimg.eventlist-hasimg.eventlist-event--multiday
    a.eventlist-column-thumbnail.content-fill(href=`${link}`)


        img(src=`${img_src}`, alt=`${img_src}`
           , style='position: static; float:left; width: 100%; object-fit: contain'
           )
```

This code achieves the following effect (the parent div is red for effect): https://lingxiaoling-1.appspot.com/code.

Some examples:

[image: bad-1.png]

[image: bad-2.png]

In conclusion I would like the images to be:
1. centered relative to the parent div
2. resize according to the size of the parent div so that it fills the parent div
3. does not overflow the parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple solutions.

a) The easiest way to make it work is to use `backgrund-image` instead of `img` tag:

```
.image {
  background-image: url(url-to-image);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

b) If the image proportions are always the seme, you make it work with `img`:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0 // or if you want to center it left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

c) or you can make a parent the same width-height ratio as parent:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: cacl(100% * (width of pic / height of pix));
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

There are probably many others.
I cannot enter your website, and you didn't provide enough of your markup and styles to reproduce exact problem, so this is all i can recommend from what you wrote above.

If neither solution will solve your problem, you will need to post more markup and css, to get help.

Comment: That's what I'm usually doing, but sometimes when using templates or when working with CMS systems it is not worth the changing the HTML structure. How would you make an image to fit into it's parent element when the parent is a fixed size?